# What is the difference among Android subversions for GCM?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I've implemented a feature that uses GCM push to deliver push messages to my a client app, however users seem unable to receive push notifications on Android subversions 4.4.4, 4.4.2, 4.2.2, and 4.1.2. (5.0, 4.4, 4.2, and 4.1 are all fine)

Is there a common difference between these subversions and their main counterparts, or is this indicative that something is incorrect with my logging?

Comment: I believe android subversion doesn't really matter. Can you show us how do you register a device in the client side?

Comment: That's what I thought as well. It'll take me a while to get code for how the device is registered client side, but I can try.